# I accepted a job at first but rhen turned it down. How do I handle this on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-acceptance

A few weeks ago I accepted a job. However before I worked there or even had training, I turned it down. I felt like a few things that happened during the process didn't feel right so I turned it down. How should I handle this on my resume?

Comment: Why would it be on your resume?  You never worked there.

Comment: @mcknz Not quite the same as this person actually didn't even work there...

Comment: The resume exists to show you have the experience and training (I.e. Education and/or OJT) to justify hiring you.  So the resume should only contain that information.  You accepting a job then turning around and changing your mind doesn't accomplish that goal.  You should be honest on your resume, but work experience in McDonalds for instance is only relevant if you want a job at Burger King (or if you have no other work experience)

Answer (score 12):

Your resume should only contain job experience.  As you never worked there you don't need to put it at all on the resume as it's not "experience" at that job.